# Java API to get quarterly revenue data from yahoo finace

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Can someone please guide me to get the data in csv format from the yahoo finance
eg: need quaterly data for five year(s) from the link: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=CSCO.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get the past (your date range) data.

> http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=X(where X is your stock name or code)